# ¿Son necesarios las llaves primarias en registros únicos?

Tags: postgresql

Tengo una tabla con registros de ventas, con 13 columnas y 2 llaves foráneas(FK) y puedo garantizar que cada registro es y será único. Entonces pregunto: Es necesario asignar llaves primarias(PK)?. Influye en las consultas e inserciones las PK?
No habrás modificaciones en los registros y estoy trabajando en Postgresql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si estás controlando la unicidad de los registros en tu tabla desde un sistema, no hay ningún problema con ello. Pero hay cosas que se te escaparían respecto a sacar provecho del motor de base de datos.

El mismo al momento de realizar la lectura de los registros, se apoya en los índices generados, y uno de ellos es el de la clave primaria; indexando tus registros antes de filtrarlos y dandote velocidad al momento de obtener tus consultas. Algo parecido puedes obtener al generar índices personalizados pero el mandatorio es el de la clave primaria.

Como recomendación y buenas prácticas te sugeriría que te apoyes en una clave primaria, que no sea muy extensa, es decir una clave compuesta pero de no muchas columnas.

Espero esta pequeña explicación haya cubierto en algo tus dudas. Saludos.

Comment: Si la tabla ha de tener llave primaria, sería se 5 columnas, qué haría? No quiero que en un futuro se ralentice en las inserciones por tantos PKs. Una PK artificial no me ayuda.

Comment: Bueno en ese caso, lo que debes hacer es un análisis de tus datos o lo que va guardar la tabla. Es realmente necesario tener 5 columnas conformando la clave primaria compuesta?. En lo que he trabajado 5 no es del todo malo, de cierta forma es tolerable y sigues aprovechando el potencial del motor, pero si puedes reducirlo a 4 estaría bien. Otra cosa que puedes hacer, es apoyarte en índices personalizados y constraints para optimizar la inserción y lectura en la datos. Saludos.

Comment: ¡muchas gracias!